# Testing for existence of a property (i.e. numberOfValidItemsForDrop)

Tags: macos, cocoa

My general question is if and how it is possible to test to see if an arbitrary object supports a given property.   For methods, this is simple. I would send a respondsToSelector: message to the object and check the result.   I cannot find a similar mechanism for properties.

My specific problem at hand is that I'm writing a custom NSView that supports dropping of image files (plural) onto it.  I am building on 10.9 and deploying on 10.6.  For machines running 10.7 and later, I would like to take advantage of the user feedback provided in the drag image (number and acceptable files) by `enumerateDraggingItemsWithOptions:...` method and the `numberOfValidItemsForDrop` property.

My initial thought is as follows. Test the sender (declared id < NSDraggingInfo >) provided to the `draggingEntered:` method.  If so, use the mechanisms provided in 10.7.  If not, go back to the earlier mechanisms.

```
if( [sender respondsToSelector:@selector(enumerateDraggingItemsWithOptions:forView:classes:searchOptions:usingBlock:) ] )
{
  __block NSInteger n=0;
  [sender enumerateDraggingItemsWithOptions:NSDraggingItemEnumerationClearNonenumeratedImages
                                    forView:self
                                    classes:types
                              searchOptions:options
                                 usingBlock:^(NSDraggingItem *draggingItem, NSInteger idx, BOOL *stop) { ++n; } ];
   self.numberOfValidItemsForDrop = n;
   rval = (n>0 ? NSDragOperationCopy : NSDragOperationNone);
} 
else
{
  NSArray *itemsInDrag = [[sender draggingPasteboard] readObjectsForClasses:types options:options];
  rval = [itemsInDrag count]>0 ? NSDragOperationCopy : NSDragOperationNone); 
}
```

**My concern is whether or not the assignment to the numberOfValidItemsForDrop will cause problems in the 10.6 environment.**  I threw together a quick test in which I assigned to a bogus property inside an if(0) condition and the compiler choked.

```
if(0)
{
   sender.bogus=1;
}
```

This is not really the same thing as the property is not valid in the development environment.  But, it has me concerned that the assignment to numberOfValidItemsForDrop might also have a problem at runtime on 10.6 even though it should never actually be executed.

I have thrown together a small dummy application which I have sent to my tester, but have not yet heard back and would like to keep moving on this project.

Thanks for any/all info.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Objective-C runtime function `class_getProperty` to test for the existence of a named property:

```
if(class_getProperty([self class], "numberOfValidItemsForDrop")) {
  // property exists
}
```

See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html

Comment: I will try that.  And will check out the reference as well.

Comment: That answers the testing half of the question in a much more direct manner than I was proposing (testing a related method).   But I still have my greater question as to whether setting the property inside the if clause will be safe if the property does not exist.

Comment: I think only to check for a property Obj-C runtime is a costly affair.

Comment: @MikeMayer67 Wouldn't you only set the property if `class_getProperty` returned non-`NULL` and you were assured of its existence?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Why is using the Objective-C runtime costly?

Comment: @sbooth My concern is really nothing more than paranoia arising from not understanding the underpinnings of how the compiler and runtime handle the dot notation.  If I include a statement that uses a completely bogus property, the compiler raises an error.  It does not defer to the runtime to determine if the property can be set.   What you proposed is exactly what I plan on doing... I was simply hoping someone could give me a warm fuzzy this will be ok when run under 10.6

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Even if this were a runtime costly call, it is being done in response to a dragging event.  I doubt anyone would be able to drop files at anywhere near a high enough rate as to notice.

Answer (score 1):

To check if a property exists or not, you can use as : *the property is assumed not to be `readonly`*.

```
if ([yourClassObject respondsToSelector:@selector(set<yourPropertyName>:)]) {
    NSLog(@"yes it exists");
}
else{
    NSLog(@"no it doesn't exists");
}
```

Comment: Is this fundamentally any different than using class_getProperty() as suggested by sbooth?